# Sitecore C# - move up / down an item in the same folder

Tags: sitecore

The title says everything about my question

On sitecore 6.6 I have to order the items in a folder and I've been google it for few days with no success.

Can anybody help ?  I've tried setting up __Sortorder field but I get an error saying that the property is readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you wrote ("but I get an error saying that the property is readonly"), you haven't started editing the item before changing the `Sort Order` field value.

Simplest code is:

```cs
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Sortorder] = "25"; // or any other new value
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

`Editing.BeginEdit()` and `Editing.EndEdit()` are required before and after every item change operation.

In older Sitecore versions devs used to use `using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(item))` instead, but from what I remember it's not recommended anymore.

Here is a sample article about Sitecore item editing: [How to edit an Item in Code Behind](http://www.nehemiahj.com/2012/03/how-to-edit-item-in-code-behind-5.html)

Comment: Property or indexer 'Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.this[Sitecore.Data.ID]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: My mistake. Code fixed. It should be `item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Sortorder] = "25";` instead of `item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Sortorder] = "25";`

Comment: You should update your answer. Thank you for this :-) The problem was this syntax "item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Sortorder] " though, which used at the beginning too.

Answer (score 1):

The __Sortorder template field has a "Read only" checkbox that you can use to allow the field to be written to.

You can use the Sorting buttons in the Home menu:

1. Select the item to move/sort
2. Open the Home menu
3. Use the Up/Down/First/Last buttons in the Sorting section

Or the keyboard shortcuts:

- Up: (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Up)
- Down: (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down)

Comment: I want to do this by code in C#. Can you tell me though where exactly can I find that check box ? Maybe if I change its value, it will work ..

Comment: Sorry, the question didn't indicate that you wanted to do this programmatically. It's in the base Template template iirc. You can search for the __Sortorder item to find it. As long as you have an edit context it should update.